# visudo/sudoedit and gvim --remote-silent

Tags: gvim, sudoedit

Is it possible to use `gvim --remote-silent` and similar as an editor for visudo and sudoedit? Actually, I don't think this is related to the `--remote` option. Even if I set `Defaults editor = "/usr/bin/gvim"`, the tmpfile gvim loads is blank and editing it has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gvim returns almost immediately. When sudoedit notices that the editor has returned it will finish reporting no changes. To get sudoedit to work correctly you need to get it to wait until you are finished editing. I normally use -f switch to do this. I have not tried it but the manual seems to support the use of --remote-wait or --remote-wait-silent.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but `--remote-wait` doesn't work any better. `-f` does work, though!

Answer (score 2):

You could try this using the environment variables:

- EDITOR
- SUDO_EDITOR
- VISUAL

And setting one/all to this:

```
"/usr/bin/gvim --remote-silent"
```

Comment: My understanding of the documentation is that I should be able to specify a list of acceptable editors like `Defaults editor = "/usr/bin/vim:/usr/bin/gvim:/usr/bin/gvim --remote-silent"`, and have sudo choose the editor in EDITOR as long as it's from that list. However, it seems that sudoedit uses vim even if `EDITOR="/usr/bin/gvim --remote-silent"`.

Comment: Can you change it per the instructions here? http://viewsby.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/update-default-editor-for-sudoedit-to-vim/, let me know, if so I'll add this to my A.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a program called update-alternatives on my machine. Seems like a Debian/Ubuntu specific solution. For example, the default editor for my visudo without any other settings seems to be vi, not nano.

Comment: I have that on CentOS/Fedora as well.

Comment: Either way, from what I understand, update-alternatives just manages some symlinks to replace one program with another. This doesn't seem  to me to be a correct solution. I actually can force sudo to use gvim with whatever options I want if it's the only thing in the `Defaults editor` setting, but it doesn't behave correctly. IDK if this is a bug in gvim or sudo, or if I'm doing something wrong.